# Rails Project deploy with Capistrano failed SSH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, capistrano3

I have a problem with my rails project deployment.

The (a bit anonymized) error message is:

> cap aborted!
>   SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as user@host: Connection reset by peer
>
> Caused by:
>   Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer

I use Ruby 2.4.3, Rails 5.1.4 with Capistrano 3.10 on a macOS 10.13.3.
On the other side is an Ubuntu 16.04.3 server with the latest updates.

I already tried to reconfigure my sshd on my server with:

```
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 100
MaxStartups 100
```

**EDIT:** To clarify it a bit I have to add that the error occurs after some successful steps. Not the same step every time. Sometimes `bundle install` sometimes `precompile assets`

Comment: are you able to login to server by just using cmd line?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Sometimes there is a delay when I try to login after a deployment attempt.

Comment: I sometimes run into problems with ssh and capistrano on a new macbook. I found running `ssh-add -k` fixes the issue for me.

Comment: I just tried `ssh-add -k` but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: something to do with the server itself i gues

Comment: @Nithin That's what I think as well, but unfortunately I have no idea even after googling a lot :(

Comment: run `ssh-add -l` in your terminal to check if correct ssh is loaded

Comment: @Sharj The command works fine! The problem occurs only after some successful steps.